# How to run right phpunit test file, when in production code, with vim command

Tags: vim

I've mapped right now a shortcut, thus I can run php of current test file. When I develop, i split my window in two parts: in one side i keep test and in other side i keep production code. If I am on test file, thanks to

```
:map <leader>t :!vendor/bin/phpunit %<cr>
```

I can run current `phpunit` test. `%` stands for current file. I would like to be able to run a test file, also when I am on production code. Example:

```
 - src/Foo/Bar/ProductionCode.php
 - test/Foo/Bar/ProductionCodeTest.php
```

Can I map

```
<leader>t
```

so that I can run test from `ProdutionCode.php`? What I need to do each time, is `Ctrl+w Ctrl+w <leader>t`. I'll like to only run `<leader>t` command. Can someone help me?

Namespace of tests reflects that ones of production. I think a good idea could be something like

```
:map <leader>t :!vendor/bin/phpunit TESTFILE<cr>
```

where `TESTFILE` is something like this pseudocode:

```
if current file ends with Test.php
    return %
else
    fileName = % " src/Foo/Bar/ProductionCode.php
                 " src/Foo/Bar/ProductionCodeTest.php
                 " test/Foo/Bar/ProductionCodeTest.php
    return fileName
endif
```

### It is possible?

```
function! RunPhpUnit()
    let l:filename = expand('%')
    if l:filename !~# 'Test\.php$'
        let l:filename=substitute(l:filename, '\.php$', 'Test.php', '')
    endif
    let l:filename=substitute(l:filename, 'code\/classes', 'spec\/unit', '')
    return ':!vendor/bin/phpunit ' . l:filename . "\<CR>"
endfunction
:noremap <expr> <leader>t RunPhpUnit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. For simple replacements in the filename, you can use the modifiers listed under `:help filename-modifiers`, for example to turn `src` into `test`:

```
:noremap <leader>t :!vendor/bin/phpunit %:s?src?test?<cr>
```

For more complex logic (and it seems you need that), you can use a `:help :map-expression` and then use conditionals to massage the filename:

```
function! RunPhpUnit()
    let l:filename = expand('%')
    if l:filename !~# 'Test\.php$'
        call substitute(l:filename, '\.php$', 'Test.php', '')
    endif
    call substitute(l:filename, 'src', 'test', '')
    return ':!vendor/bin/phpunit ' . l:filename . "\<CR>"
endfunction
:noremap <expr> <leader>t RunPhpUnit()
```

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I am not able to modify your script. It works if I am in test code. But does not work in production code: I need to go from "code/classes/path/to/blabla.php" to "spec/unit/path/to/blablaTest.php".

Comment: Doesn't `call substitute(l:filename, 'code/classes', 'spec/unit', '')` help?

Comment: Yes, ... is condition "if l:filename !~# 'Test\.php$'" returning always true?